# Regex for pulling name out of pattern

Tags: r, regex

I'm hoping to pull full names out of the following pattern. Some names have hyphens or multiple caps as the examples given:

(all numbers inside parentheses are either 1 or 2 digits). All Capitalized city abbreviations before parentheses are either 2 or 3 chars long)

```
Davante Adams LV (6)
Christian McCaffrey CAR (10)
J.K. Dobbins BAL (5)
Amon-Ra St. Brown DET (7)
AJ Brown PHI (11)
Michael Pittman Jr. IND (14)
JuJu Smith-Schuster PIT (9)
```

Results should be...

```
Davante Adams
Christian McCaffrey
J.K. Dobbins
Amon-Ra St. Brown
AJ Brown
Michael Pittman Jr.
JuJu Smith-Schuster
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `strsplit`

```r
strsplit(str, " [A-Z]+ \\(\\d+\\) *")[[1]]
#> [1] "Davante Adams"       "Christian McCaffrey" "J.K. Dobbins"       
#> [4] "Amon-Ra St. Brown"   "AJ Brown"            "Michael Pittman Jr."
#> [7] "JuJu Smith-Schuster"
``
```

Comment: Awesome. This worked. Can you give a quick explanation on why? It's looking for a space, then one or more capital letters, then another space, then a literal (, literal digit or more, literal ). How does this account for capital letters in the name (like McCaffrey) or non word digit chars?

Comment: @JeffHenderson if it finds that _entire_ sequence it removes it and cuts the string there, so if it comes across a capital in a word name, it won't match because it is not followed by a space, then a parenthesis, etc.

Answer (score 3):

We may use `trimws` with regex as `whitespace` i.e. one or more space (`\\s+`) followed by one or more uppercase letters (`[A-Z]+`), then any space and one or more digits (`\\d+`) within the brackets

```
trimws(str1, whitespace = "\\s+[A-Z]+\\s*\\(\\d+\\)")
```

-output

```
[1] "Davante Adams"      
[2] "Christian McCaffrey" 
[3] "J.K. Dobbins"     
[4] "Amon-Ra St. Brown" 
[5]  "AJ Brown"           
[6] "Michael Pittman Jr." 
[7] "JuJu Smith-Schuster"
```

#### data

```
str1 <- c("Davante Adams LV (6)", "Christian McCaffrey CAR (10)", "J.K. Dobbins BAL (5)", 
"Amon-Ra St. Brown DET (7)", "AJ Brown PHI (11)", "Michael Pittman Jr. IND (14)", 
"JuJu Smith-Schuster PIT (9)")
```